# Whats the best way to build for multiple screen sizes?

Tags: android

I'm building an app now and I want it to work well across multiple screen sizes (phones, 7inch tablets and 10inch tablets). I've looked at the document on Supporting Multiple Screens but i still have some questions.

Right now I have 5 different layout folders, layout-: normal, large, xlarge, sw600dp and sw720dp. Is this the best way to build for all screen sizes?

And when i try to optimize each layout say the normal size which covers some 3 and 4 inch screens I get issues where I can't get my layout to look right on all of them.
What am I doing right and what could I change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that there's any best way, it will be just your way to do it. If you are planing to make the Images, buttons, textview smaller or bigger you can use the method you use or style.xml.

Style.xml example:

You will have some folders like:

- values
- values-large
- values-normal
- values-small
- values-xlarge

where inside the folders you have a styles.xml with different values:

```
<style name="BigTextStyle">
    <item name="android:textSize">60dp</item>
</style>

<style name="SmallTextStyle">
    <item name="android:textSize">48dp</item>
</style>

<style name="ImageSize">
    <item name="android:layout_width">100dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">100dp</item>
</style>
```

just change the size depending on the screen you are working with, then in the layout.xml add this:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageSD"
            style="@style/ImageSize" />

        <TextView
    android:id="@+id/imageNameSD"
            style="@style/BigTextStyle" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use this resource alias sir.

Suppose you have two different images for sw320dp and sw600dp.

- image1_sw320dp.png
- image1_sw600dp.png

Put all image resource to folder `drawable`.

The in the folder values-sw320dp, create an xml resource. (also maybe you need for values-small, just copy the xml from values-320dp)

```
<resources>
    <item type="drawable" name="image1">@drawable/image1_sw320dp</item>
</resources>
```

In folder values-sw600dp, create an xml resource.

```
<resources>
    <item type="drawable" name="image1">@drawable/image1_sw600dp</item>
</resources>
```

Then use on the activity with `R.drawable.image1`. This can prevent for creating duplicate resources for example sw320dp, small, and normal.

Answer (score 0):

Mr Rotary has a good way to work with multiple screen size. 
Furthermore You can use Fragment in your application.
You can learn how to use fragment here : http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html